# NSMutabledictionary unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this dictionary defined:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic,readwrite) NSMutableDictionary* images;
```

Along with this method:

```
-(void)initImages
{
    UIImage *sprite = [UIImage imageNamed: @"sprite"];
    [self.images 
         setObject:CFBridgingRelease(CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(sprite.CGImage, CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64))) 
         forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:black]];
}
```

And when I call:

```
    [self.images objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
```

I get

```
2014-03-02 14:51:36.831 kljlkj[7853:70b] -[__NSCFType size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b73ba0
```

Which happens on the line:

```
[self.images objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
```

If I skip the initImages function call, nothing happens and all is fine, however if I do call initImages I get the exception...

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

EDIT: Sorry everybody! I was wrong, the exception was in fact thrown on another line than I thought and makes a lot of sense. Sorry again for the waste of time

Comment: Have you tried using `stringWithFormat` instead of `numberWithFormat` ?

Comment: Are you certain the exception is thrown on the line you think its thrown on?

Comment: Double check your code for all the places where you initialize or otherwise set a value to self.images.

Comment: hey, do you get the same exception every time, or the exception message change ?

Comment: The error is not coming from the line you claim.  It is coming from somewhere where the `size` method is being invoked (and I'm right now having trouble remembering any class that has a `size` method).  The error is occurring because the object being referenced is not the type claimed.  "NSCFType" is an odd class that would not normally be explicitly used, suggesting that you have some sort of a storage management problem.  You need to run Analyzer on your project, and possibly Zombies.

Comment: Just show us the code where you do something like: `self.images = ...;` or `[self setImages:...]`.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is means that the method you're calling doesn't exist on the object on which you called it. Somethjng is wrong with self.images when you make that call.

Comment: But it isn't and array:@property (strong,nonatomic,readwrite) NSMutableDictionary* images;

Comment: Updated my answer. The point is that your  Object is not a NSDictionary, but something else. This is what the exception means.